# Is it okay to install most recent Intel chipset drivers when using old hardware?

Tags: drivers, bsod, chipset, inf

the chipset software i installed was the most recent one avaliable on intel site. It might be that since my chipset Z77 is old, i should have not installed the recent chipset?

Their Intel Driver Update Utility doesnt update to it.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/20775/Intel-Chipset-Device-Software-INF-Update-Utility-

i didnt install the mobo support site, because I see them outdated outdated, 10.1.1.8 instead of 10.1.1.42. yet the new recent one lists my chipset as supported in release notes but generally the intel site doesn't see the inf file as made for my chipset and its update software would say its already upt to date. Ia sk because im getting BSODs from directx files so wondering if its related.

Comment: Z77 hasn't reached its end of support so Intel will continue to update its chipset drivers

Comment: But Intel's own update software doesn't list any updates for it and tells you with the old 2015 INF, it's already up to date.

Comment: Why are you using update software, it takes a minute, to find the correct drivers on Intel's website

Comment: i havent, i just used it to see if i need to update or not. I dont know what the correct drivers are, since the newest ones dont list my hardware in the main page, but it supports it in the release notes.

Comment: this is what i now showing me in device manager: https://i.imgur.com/EKRdk3g.png

Comment: Install the most recent version that supports your chipset